# How can I parse a JSON file with substring array into a Swift Struct?

Tags: json, swift

I want to create a calendar that lists special events associated with a particular date interval. Since more than one event may occur within the same interval, I have an array of events in my JSON (a mock-up of which looks like this:)

```
[
    {
    "start": "2023-05-04T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2023-06-05T18:00:00Z",
    "events": [
        "Event1"
        ]
    },
    {
    "start": "2023-07-05T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2023-07-05T18:00:00Z",
    "events": [
        "Event2",
        "Event3"
        ]
    },
    {
    "start": "2023-07-14T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2023-07-15T18:00:00Z",
    "events": [
        "Event4"
        ]
    },
    {
    "start": "2023-10-14T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2023-10-14T13:00:00Z",
    "events": [
        "Event5"
        ]
    }
]
```

The two structs are as follows:

```
struct Event: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        name
    }
    var name: String
    var description: String
}

struct EventDate: Codable {
    var start: String
    var end: String
    var events: [Event]
}
```

When I decode using:

```
let allEventDates = Bundle.main.decode([EventDate].self, from: "event_dates.json")
```

I get this message in the console:
**Failed to decode event_dates.json mismatch - Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.**
I know I need to initialize the Events, but I'm stuck on this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `var events: [Event]` -> `var events: [String]`, they are just an array of String in your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Codable object

```
struct EventsRecord: Codable {
let start, end: String
let events: [String]}

let allEventDates = Bundle.main.decode([EventsRecord].self, from: "event_dates.json")
```

Hopefully you got your desired result

Comment: Thanks Chandaboy. Your suggestion worked. Much appreciation for the help.